# Bash-running a script in background

Tags: bash

I have a script(func_test) that works well when i invoke it from my terminal. I need to run the script automatically on boot-up and so i have copied it in /etc/init.d and changed its execution mode and linked it to S99func_test under /etc/rc2.d. But upon reboot I'm getting syntax error in that script. Any idea why I'm getting the error although it works fine with my terminal?
Here is the code used to invoke the script for the 1st time:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /opt/bin/
cp func_test /etc/init.d/
cp test_file /etc/init.d
chmod 755 /etc/init.d/func_test
chown root:sys /etc/init.d/func_test
ln /etc/init.d/func_test /etc/rc2.d/S99func_test
ln /etc/init.d/test_file /etc/rc2.d/S99test_file
```

(the script is dependent on another file(test_file) and i have copied the same to init.d)

Comment: Without seeing that script ist's hard to tell what goes wrong ;-). But in general the reason mut be in the different environment of an interactive bash compared to a non-interactive one (no bashrc is read etc.)

Comment: I'm (wildly) guessing it has `#!/bin/sh` instead of `#!/bin/bash` and init doesn't use bash to interpret the init scripts.

Comment: A nice diagram about the startup files involved, dependent on the startup options, is at the bottom of this page: http://capistranorb.com/documentation/faq/why-does-something-work-in-my-ssh-session-but-not-in-capistrano/

Comment: @Wintermute that doesn't work :( I have declared a variable using declare keyword. but it throws an error stating "declare:not found" So i have a doubt whether the script is interpreted as bash or some other

Answer (score 0):

Probably you forgot slash at the end of line

```
    cp test_file /etc/init.d/
```

and I recommend to use `./` to copy files from current directory:

```
cp ./func_test /etc/init.d/
```